# jq: flip or transpose to dict object

Tags: json, stream, jq, transpose

Here my document:

```json
{
   "id":"06b6751f-5125-4e48-b588-fcc8ff56004f",
   "dni":"78081181"
}
{
   "id":"4bdcf9e9-4a3e-4e13-963d-1270b94955dc",
   "dni":"77834021"
}
```

I need to get:

```
{
"78081181": "06b6751f-5125-4e48-b588-fcc8ff56004f",
"77834021": "4bdcf9e9-4a3e-4e13-963d-1270b94955dc"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No comma between the two objects in the input?

Comment: @choroba Yes, that's a valid stream of objects. It wouldn't be with commas in between (unless also surrounded by brackets, which would make it an array instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object can be transformed using the `{ (.value) : (.key) }` formula. Use `-s` to read all the objects to an array, merge all the objects into one with `add`.

```
jq  -s '[ .[] | { (.dni) : (.id) } ] | add' doc.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input file entirely fits into your memory, use `--slurp` and `reduce`:

```sh
jq --slurp 'reduce .[] as $k ({}; .[$k.dni] = $k.id)'
```

```json
{
  "78081181": "06b6751f-5125-4e48-b588-fcc8ff56004f",
  "77834021": "4bdcf9e9-4a3e-4e13-963d-1270b94955dc"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XRL6R33t6S)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce memory requirements to a minimum (at least within the realm of jq):

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; . + ($in | {(.dni): .id}))' input.jstream
```